# Query e Subquery no codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, active-record

Salve Galera , estou quebrando a cuca para montar essa query na model do CI

```
"SELECT *, geral_cnpj as cnpj, geral_mesref as mesref, (SELECT CEILING(( (SELECT `geral_valor_total` as valormes from tbl_geral where `geral_cnpj`=cnpj and `geral_mesref`=mesref) - (SELECT `geral_valor_total`from tbl_geral as valormesanterior where `geral_cnpj`=cnpj and `geral_mesref`=mesref-1) ) / (SELECT `geral_valor_total`as valormes from tbl_geral where `geral_cnpj`=cnpj and `geral_mesref`=mesref)*100 ) ) as valor_percentual FROM tbl_geral";
```

A *query* está correta, pois já rodei no MySQL e traz os resultados. Tentei utilizar dessa forma (que acredito que não esta correto) e me dá o erro

```
Error Number: HY000/1096
No tables used
SELECT *
```

segue o method abaixo da model

```
public function listar_gerais_percentual(){

   $q="SELECT *, geral_cnpj as cnpj, geral_mesref as mesref, (SELECT CEILING(( (SELECT `geral_valor_total` as valormes from tbl_geral where `geral_cnpj`=cnpj and `geral_mesref`=mesref) - (SELECT `geral_valor_total`from tbl_geral as valormesanterior where `geral_cnpj`=cnpj and `geral_mesref`=mesref-1) ) / (SELECT `geral_valor_total`as valormes from tbl_geral where `geral_cnpj`=cnpj and `geral_mesref`=mesref)*100 ) ) as valor_percentual FROM tbl_geral";



  $result = $this->db->query($q); 

  return $result;

}
```

Comment: [ERRO MYSQL 1096 - SEM TABELAS USADAS - CODEIGNITER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927940/mysql-error-1096-no-tables-used-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá! `$this->db->query()` não é parte do Active Record do CI, mas `$this->db->get()` sim, e este é um erro que aparece quando uma consulta foi mal montada via query builder. Por exemplo, chamado o método `get()` sem nome de tabela, ou sem ter especificado via `from()`.

O erro não parece estar nesta função que você mostrou. Verifique se no seu controle não há outras chamadas para outros métodos do modelo. É provável que em alguma outra função do modelo esteja sobrando um `get()` desnecessário, ou haja uma tal consulta mal configurada.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pela ajuda, porém resolvi dessa forma:

$query = $this->db->query($q);

return $query->result_array();

//// NO CONTROLER ficou

$this->load->model('Dados_model', 'dados');

```
    $dados['gerais']=$this->dados->listar_gerais_percentual();
```

OBS: Tentarei utilizar o get() como estudo pra ver se tbem da certo (acredito q ai preciso chamar